# Is it possible to show the annotations of method parameters in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, annotations, javadoc

We use the annotations **@javax.annotation.Nullable** and **@javax.annotation.Nonnull** to document the behavior of method parameters.

Is it possible to show this annotations in the JavaDoc popup in Eclipse? I means the popup that occur if I move with the mouse over a method. Currently Eclipse show only the annotations of the method self but not of the parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Indigo SR1 [Java EE version], and it does exactly this.

I didn't configure it specifically, so I think its something that was added.

[image: Screenshot]

As pointed out, the above is not for **annotated parameters**.

If you hold down **SHIFT** before hovering over the method, it will show the annotations for the different parameters.

The full build information of Eclipse:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149
```

Comment: This is the annotation of the **method** not the parameter of the method as the OP wanted.

Comment: Refined the answer to point out how to show parameter annotations.